# Linking CSS to images in a subfolder

Tags: css, url, directory-structure

I cant figure out the right path to use in my CSS file for

```
    html { background-image: url('backgroundImage.jpg'); }
```

My folder structure is as follows:

`..\MySite\  <!-- HTML files here -->`

`..\MySite\css\`

`..\MySite\js\`

`..\MySite\images\ <!-- backgroundImage.jpg here -->`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 html{ background-image: url('../images/backgroundImage.jpg'); }
```

`../` is telling your CSS file to go one directory back and search for the image from that folder (in this case your root folder)

Answer (score 3):

use `html{ background-image: url('/images/backgroundImage.jpg'); }`

starting with `/` means you start at the root of your site

Answer (score 0):

Pretty trivial question. If you are using inline styles (styles inside HTML files) then the following will suffice.

```
html { 
    background-image: url('images/backgroundImage.jpg'); 
}
```

However if you are referencing images from within the `css` folder you'll have to use `..` traversal to reach the parent folder first.

```
html { 
    background-image: url('../images/backgroundImage.jpg'); 
}
```

Comment: I don't like rooting my CSS with absolute links because it often interferes with mod_rewrite especially when `RewriteBase` needs to be changed.